# Regex negative match at end of string

Tags: regex

I need an regex that match

"my dog", "My dog", "my &dog"

but not

"my dog#", "My dog#"

for search string "my dog". I have this expression at the moment by I have this:

```
reg_replace("/\b(my dog)\b/ui",'found','My dog');
```

But this obviously matches "my dog#" and not "My &dog". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `\bmy &?dog(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/bDEfxD/1 Or `\bmy &?dog(?!#)`

Comment: `\bmy dog\b(?!#)` - you need a *negative lookahead*.

Answer (score -2):

my..?dog$

. = any Space
.? = 0 or 1 of any Space

$ = end of string

As not casesensitive this doesnt matter.
If you only have these, you can make a ".?" to get this one Dog with "&"
with end of string, you can simply get these other dogs you dont want out there.

Tested with regex101, if only these values are there, this is enough.
Flags = gsmi (Global, Multiline, singleline, insensitive)